# Dropping PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server

I have created a table which has two columns combined as a primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Workflow_Name]
(
  [Workflow_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Unique_Workflow_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Workflow_Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [Row_ID] [int] NULL,
  [ReleaseVersion] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [Release] [varchar](255) NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkFlowName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([Workflow_ID] ASC, [Unique_Workflow_ID] ASC )
)
```

As seen , **[Workflow_ID] ASC,  [Unique_Workflow_ID] ASC** combined together are forming the Primary key.

[image]

Now i want to remove [Unique_Workflow_ID] from the Primary key constraint and maintain only [Workflow_ID] as Primary Key.

How to do it?

Comment: What reasearches are done to solve the problem? Which part of the tried solution did not work? What did you try so far? [Hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190621.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by executing the following statements in SSMS Query Window after selecting the database that the table is in.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workflow_Name] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkFlowName]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workflow_Name] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkFlowName] PRIMARY KEY ([Workflow_ID] ASC)
```

Please note, in order for it to work, if you have existing rows in the `[Workflow_Name]`, then the data in this new single column Primary Key i.e. in `[Workflow_ID]` must be unique per row. Otherwise the `ALTER` statement will (rightly) throw an error that data is not unique in that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your primary key constraint and then create a new one only with the Workflow_ID. But make sure it has only unique values.